# list index comparison in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, comparison

By list index comparison I mean that I have two lists which I sorted using different methods (bubblesort and insertion sort) according to 2 different criteria. I would now like to compare if an element in one of the list is in the same position in the other list and if so return its position.
So for I have

```
List1 = selectionsort()
List2 = bubblesort()
indices = [List1.index(i) for i in List2]
print (str(indices))
```

I know this is not right because it compares the elements of List1 to List2 elements and returns the positions at which they match (i think). Furthermore this sort of implies that List1 is a subset of List2, which it is not, the two list are the same just ordered differently

Comment: You forgot to use comparison operators :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the matching indices like this

```
list1, list2 = [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 3]
print [index for index, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if e1 == e2]
```

**Output**

```
[0, 2]
```

We are first zipping both the lists with [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). So, on every iteration, we will get elements at corresponding positions from both the lists. And then we run it with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) which will return a tuple with the index and the actual element from the iterable. We retain the index, if the elements match.

**Edit:** For the particular input given by you in the comments section

```
list1, list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
print [index for index, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if e1 == e2]
```

**Output**

```
[2]
```

Comment: hey this seems very helpful, however I don't think it is what i am looking for. Maybe I should make myself clearer:
For example
`list1 = [a, b, c, d, e]
list2 = [e, d, c, b, a]`
So c is in the same position for both lists, how do i retrieve its index (2) and how do I do this for multiple values
Or will the function you gave me work in that way?

Comment: @sbhb91 Please edit the question and explain the problem clearly,  and give sample inputs and expected output.

Comment: @sbhb91 Please try the program I have given in the answer. It will work your inputs. Please confirm after checking.

Comment: It does work, sorry I had not yet tried it, thank you very much

Comment: I am having more troubles now, how would I print the elements at the particular indices in the list!!? I thought:
`coincidences = [index for index, (e1, e2) in enumerate(zip(CountriesArea, CountriesPop)) if e1 == e2]

for i in coincidences:
    print (str(i))`

But nope that doesnt work...this is supposed to be really simple but its very late here and I am loosing my mind

Comment: @sbhb91 `for i in coincidences: print(CountriesArea[i])`